# Should I maintain different files for different locales?

Tags: localization, internationalization, locale, l10n.js

I have an application that currently support 'en' and 'fr' locales, and maintain one language file for each locale i.e. 'en.json' and 'fr.json'

Now for the user from USA, locale comes in as "en_US", Canada 'en_CA', British 'en_UK' etc.

So now as a best practice, is it recommended that I maintain different files for different English Locales or I treat all English locales (en_CA, en_US, en_UK) as 'en' locale and refer to one file for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, it depends.

Typically, you will only have one English file, containing English-international messages. In this case, you won't maintain separate files for each version, but instead you will fall back to English international (having a request for *en-US*, *en-CA*, etc. you will serve messages from `en.json`).

Judging by your nickname, you probably know that sometimes it is better to maintain separate messages for some specific cultures for which English-US messages (typically used as international English) might be simply way too direct.
If there is a request for separate locale version (i.e. *en-IN*), you would serve messages from the specific file (i.e. `en-IN.json`), but fall back to *en* for each other language (*en-GB*, *en-AU*, etc.).

Resource fall-back (which is the term specialists use for what I described above) could be quite painful to implement. Sure, usually you would fall back to base language (*en* for any *en-XX*), but there are some corner cases which you need to know: Portuguese/Brazilian Portuguese, Norwegian and Chinese. In case of Portuguese you should use *pt-BR* (i.e. `pt-BR.json`) and for requests to *pt* or *pt-XX* fall back to *pt-BR*, as Brazilian Portuguese is now the standard one. Obviously, it could be easily done by simply creating one file `pt.json` and let anything fall back to *pt*.

This is not the case for neither Norwegian nor Chinese.

There are two versions of Norwegian language:

- Norwegian Nynorsk (locale *nn-NO*)
- Norwegian Bokmål (locale *nb-NO*)

There is also so-called macro language (locale *no*).
Unless you maintain two separate versions of Norwegian (which is unlikely), you should use one resource file (i.e. `no.json` <- sounds funny, isn't it?) and fall back to it for any requests for *nn-NO*, *nb-NO*, *nb*, *nn* and *no-NO* (I believe simply *no* will be covered).

The Chinese is even more complicated. You may have heard about Chinese Simplified (locale *zh-Hans*) and Chinese Traditional (*zh-Hant*). If you'll ever need to localize into Chinese, it make sense to maintain two separate Chinese files (i.e. `zh-Hans.json` and `zh-Hant.json`) and fall back any requests as follows:

- *zh*, *zh-CN* and *zh-SG* to *zh-Hans*
- *zh-HG*, *zh-MO* and *zh-TW* to *zh-Hant*

I hope it gives you better understanding. It is worth to consider future localization plans to implement the resource fall-back mechanism as simple as it could be done (but no simpler). If you'll ever need to support languages like English, French, Italian, German and Spanish, there is no point in implementing complex rules - simply check if `xx-XX.json` exists and serve it if it does, if not check if `xx.json` exists (serve it...) or fall-back to default application language (`en.json`, I guess?).